# Issue in curve fitting

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize

I am having a problem in curve fitting a function.
In fact, when defining the function as hard code, it works perfectly. Please consider the example below:

create array of Y data

```
ydata= np.array([5.37E+04, 3.36E+04, 1.99E+04, 1.12E+04, 5.96E+03, 3.02E+03, 1.45E+03, 6.67E+02, 2.98E+02, 1.29E+02, 5.59E+01, 2.44E+01, 1.09E+01, 4.71E+00, 2.46E+00, 1.25E+00])
```

create array of X data

```
xdata = np.array([300., 188., 118., 73.6, 46.0, 28.8, 18.0, 11.3, 7.06, 4.42, 2.77, 1.73, 1.08, 0.678, 0.425, 0.266])
```

define my fitting function

```
def fit_storage (w,G0, G1, t1, G2, t2, G3, t3, G4, t4, G5, t5, G6, t6, G7, t7):
fit_str = G0 + (G1*w**2*t1**2)/(1+w**2*t1**2) + (G2*w**2*t2**2)/(1+w**2*t2**2) + (G3*w**2*t3**2)/(1+w**2*t3**2) + (G4*w**2*t4**2)/(1+w**2*t4**2) + (G5*w**2*t5**2)/(1+w**2*t5**2) + (G6*w**2*t6**2)/(1+w**2*t6**2) + (G7*w**2*t7**2)/(1+w**2*t7**2)
return fit_str
```

Than, I am calling curve_fit (imported from scipy):

```
popt, pcov = curve_fit(fit_storage, xdata, ydata, bounds=(bound_lower, bound_upper), maxfev = 50000)
```

This works perfectly, but as you can see it is totally hard coded the coefficients. Thus, I am trying to do a more generic function, defined as:

```
def str_func(w, x, n):
summation_str = np.array(np.zeros(len(frequency)))
for i in range (1,2*n+1,2): 
    summation_str = summation_str + ((x[i]*w**2*x[i+1]**2)/(1+(w**2*x[i+1]**2))) 
y_str = x[0] + summation_str
return y_str
```

However, I am not being able to call the curve fit on it. The way I am doing is the following:

```
popt, pcov = curve_fit(str_func, xdata, ydata, bounds=([bound_lower], [bound_upper]), maxfev = 50000)
```

And it does not work... Could anybody help me to fix this issue (you can consider any bound_lower and bound_upper... the error is not in there)? Thanks in advance.

Comment: 'it does not work' - can you describe how it doesn't work?

Comment: Please post an MCVE. You start well, but then introduce a bunch of undefined variables

Comment: The function you pass to curve_fit should be an equation relating x and y. That doesn't appear to be what you have done